# SQL conditional Where with limits and previous value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains sensor data `data1` and the allowed (alarm) limits for that sensor data `data1high` and `data1low`. I wish to create a view where only those data1 values are listed which are the first to move outside the limits (i.e. an alarm condition) or moved back in within "safe" limits (alarm condition no longer present).

Here is a typical table:

```
| id | data1 | data1high | data1low | 
|----|-------|-----------|----------|
|  1 |    60 |       200 |      100 |
|  2 |    80 |       200 |      100 |
|  3 |   123 |       200 |      100 |
|  4 |   150 |       200 |      100 |
|  5 |    60 |       200 |      100 |
|  6 |    60 |       200 |      100 | 
|  7 |   150 |       200 |      100 |
|  8 |    40 |       200 |      100 |
|  9 |    58 |       200 |      100 |
| 10 |    62 |       200 |      100 |
| 11 |   300 |       200 |      100 |
```

The logic is that values within `where data1 < data1low OR data1 > data1high` are in the alarm condition and should be listed.

For example,

```
| id | data1 |
|----|-------|
|  1 |    60 |
|  2 |    80 |
|  5 |    60 |
|  6 |    60 |
|  8 |    40 |
|  9 |    58 |
| 10 |    62 |
| 11 |   300 |
```

The table above shows all the values in the alarm state. I do not want this, only those that have just transitioned into that state and those which first values where the data1 goes back to within safe limits, so my ideal view would be:

```
| id | data1 | data1high | data1low | 
|----|-------|-----------|----------|
|  1 |    60 |       200 |      100 |
|  3 |   123 |       200 |      100 |
|  5 |    60 |       200 |      100 | 
|  7 |   150 |       200 |      100 |
|  8 |    40 |       200 |      100 |
| 11 |   300 |       200 |      100 |
```

id 1 is in alarm state so listed, id 2 is omitted because that was still in the alarm state, id 3 is listed because that is the next value to be back in limits, id 4 is omitted because that is still within limits, id 5 is listed because that is back outside limits etc ...

Comment: What version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: I didn't get the logic :(

Comment: could you please be more elaborate. Going through the logic,I have one question the first two instances are provided to you right. You want the third snapshot of data. Correct me if I am wrong. @user3238504

Comment: @user3238504 Why 10 and 11 appear, 8 is out of limits and the they still out of them ?

Comment: @wewesthemenace - version 11.

Comment: @54l3d - 10 should not appear - edited.

Comment: @user3238504, Why is 11 still included? 9, 10, is out of limits, so 11 does no go back to being back in limits.

Comment: @user3238504, which version of sql?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, he said 11? Is that SQL-Server 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to iterate over the rows and compare one row to the previous row, applying the logic of what you classify as a transition.

Looking at your desired output though, I don't think `id = 10` should appear in the list as it hasn't transitioned.

Here's a sample that you can run in isolation to test:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data1
    (
      [id] INT ,
      [data1] INT ,
      [data1high] INT ,
      [data1low] INT
    );

INSERT  INTO #Data1
        ( [id], [data1], [data1high], [data1low] )
VALUES  ( 1, 60, 200, 100 ),
        ( 2, 80, 200, 100 ),
        ( 3, 123, 200, 100 ),
        ( 4, 150, 200, 100 ),
        ( 5, 60, 200, 100 ),
        ( 6, 60, 200, 100 ),
        ( 7, 150, 200, 100 ),
        ( 8, 40, 200, 100 ),
        ( 9, 58, 200, 100 ),
        ( 10, 62, 200, 100 ),
        ( 11, 300, 200, 100 );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT TOP 1
                        id ,
                        data1 ,
                        data1high ,
                        data1low ,
                        CASE WHEN data1 < data1low
                                  OR data1 > data1high THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                        END AS Transitioned
               FROM     #Data1
               ORDER BY id
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   #Data1.id ,
                        #Data1.data1 ,
                        #Data1.data1high ,
                        #Data1.data1low ,
                        CASE WHEN cte.data1 < cte.data1low
                                  AND #Data1.data1 < #Data1.data1low THEN 0
                             WHEN cte.data1 > cte.data1high
                                  AND #Data1.data1 < #Data1.data1high THEN 0
                             WHEN cte.data1 BETWEEN cte.data1low AND cte.data1high
                                  AND #Data1.data1 BETWEEN #Data1.data1low
                                                   AND     #Data1.data1high
                             THEN 0
                             WHEN cte.Transitioned = 1
                                  AND #Data1.data1 BETWEEN #Data1.data1low
                                                   AND     #Data1.data1high
                             THEN 1
                             ELSE 1
                        END AS Transitioned
               FROM     #Data1
                        INNER JOIN cte ON cte.id + 1 = #Data1.id
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   cte.Transitioned = 1

DROP TABLE #Data1
```

Within the CTE, a column is added to mark rows that have transitioned. The `CASE WHEN` clauses contain what I can gauge as the logic you require to asses if a transition has taken place compared to the previous row.

At the end of the CTE, you can simply select all rows where `Transitioned = 1`, to produce:

```
id  data1   data1high   data1low    Transitioned
1   60      200         100         1
3   123     200         100         1
5   60      200         100         1
7   150     200         100         1
8   40      200         100         1
11  300     200         100         1
```

### [Working Demo SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f944/1)

Comment: thank you for this comprehensive solution - it seems you have understood my logic perfectly and provided a working solution :-) You were correct that id 10 was a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL-Server 2012, you can use the `LAG` function:

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to get all records that changed from being in alarm to not being in alarm. If that is the case, shouldn't be 11 not in the result set? The last change is 8. Records in between ( 9 and 10) is still in alarm, so is 11, so this should not be included.

```
WITH CteAlarm AS(
    SELECT *,
        alarm = CASE WHEN data1 < data1low OR data1 > data1high THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM test
),
Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        prevAlarm = LAG(alarm) OVER(ORDER BY id)
    FROM CteAlarm
)
SELECT * 
FROM Cte
WHERE 
    alarm <> prevAlarm
    OR (prevAlarm IS NULL AND alarm = 1)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8dbb6/2/0)

Comment: This is nearly the correct logic. I want to capture the transition from in and out of alarm. @Tanner has the correct logic and result.

Comment: @user3238504, but why is 11 still included? It's still hasn't changed from being in alarm since the record 8?

Comment: It has changed from the low alarm condition to the high alarm condition. I guess that is why I was suggesting it was more a transition detector ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      id INT ,
      data1 INT ,
      data1high INT ,
      data1low INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 60, 200, 100 ),
        ( 2, 80, 200, 100 ),
        ( 3, 123, 200, 100 ),
        ( 4, 150, 200, 100 ),
        ( 5, 60, 200, 100 ),
        ( 6, 60, 200, 100 ),
        ( 7, 150, 200, 100 ),
        ( 8, 40, 200, 100 ),
        ( 9, 58, 200, 100 ),
        ( 10, 62, 200, 100 ),
        ( 11, 300, 200, 100 )


;WITH t AS(SELECT *, CASE WHEN data1 < data1low or data1 > data1high THEN 1 ELSE 0 END b
           FROM @t)
SELECT * FROM t t1 
WHERE b <> (SELECT TOP 1 b FROM t t2 WHERE t2.id < t1.id ORDER BY t2.id DESC) OR
      id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM t) OR
      id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM t)
```